# Unable to accept incoming calls on Polycom VVX 410

Tags: networking, router, firewall, voip, sip

I'm using a Cisco DPC3848 cable modem running in bridge mode.

I have a microtik CRS125-24G-1S-2HnD router behind it.

I can make outbound calls on it no problem, but if I try to make an inbound call to it doesn't work and the error I get from the freeswitch is:

ITU-T Q.850 Code 102
SIP Equiv. 504
RECOVERY_ON_TIMER_EXPIRE
recovery on timer expiry [Q.850]
This cause indicates that a procedure has been initiated by the expiration of a timer in association with error handling procedures. This is often associated with NAT problems. Ensure that "NAT Mapping Enable" is turned on in your ATA. If it is not NAT related it can sometimes be provider related, make sure to ensure another outbound provider does not solve the problem.
FreeSWITCH also returns this when the remote party sends a 408 for call expired.

I also have a Grandstream GXP1625, and it doesn't have any issues at all to make inbound or outbound calls, so I suspect there's some setting that this Polycom just doesn't like.

*** UPDATE ***

I should mention that I had this previously working no problem before when I was using DSL using a Sagecom F@st 2864 modem also in bridge mode, so I feel like the cable modem is doing something different than the previous DSL mode.

Comment: Try disabling [SIP ALG on the Microtik](http://support.clouditsp.com/index.php?/Knowledgebase/Article/View/78/0/how-to-disable-sip-alg-on-a-mikrotik) - a broken SIP ALG can often lead to problems with inbound calls.

Comment: @DavidPostill thanks for your suggestion, however I've tried with that setting both on and off without any success.